# Docx no reconoce "paragraph_format"

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

estoy intentando crear un documento usando docx con caracter{isticas específicas. El problema es que al final, el programa no corre el atributo **".paragraph_format"** en el objeto footer. Abajo dejo el error de la terminal y el código reproducible. He buscado tutoriales en internet y no veo el error. Si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias.

> footer.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT
> AttributeError: '_Footer' object has no attribute 'paragraph_format'

```
import mysql.connector
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

# Establecer la conexión con la base de datos MySQL
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()

# Ejecutar una consulta SQL y almacenar los resultados en una variable
cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM ticket")
results=cursor1.fetchall()

# Crear un nuevo documento de Word
document = Document()

# Crear un nuevo estilo de párrafo personalizado
style = document.styles.add_style('CustomFont', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)

# Establecer la fuente y el tamaño de los caracteres en el estilo
style.font.name = 'Arial'
style.font.size = Pt(12)

# Agregar un título al documento
document.add_heading('Título del documento', 0)

# Obtener la primera sección del documento
section = document.add_section()
section.page_width = Inches(8.5)
section.page_height = Inches(11)
section.top_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.bottom_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.left_margin = Inches(0.75)
# Define margins
section.right_margin = Inches(0.75)

# Agregar el membrete
header = section.header
header.add_paragraph('Membrete de la empresa')

# Recorrer los resultados de la consulta y agregar cada fila al documento
for row in results:
    for element in row:
        document.add_paragraph(str(element))
    document.add_paragraph('')

# Agregar la fecha a pie de página
footer = section.footer
footer.add_paragraph('Fecha: ')
footer.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT

# Guardar el documento
document.save("document.docx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Tal como dice la documentación, [`docx.section._Footer`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html?highlight=footer#docx.section._Footer) no tiene `paragraph_format`.

Lo que debes hacer es primero crear un párrafo `parrafo = footer.add_paragraph('Fecha: ')` y a ese párrafo le puedes configurar
`WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT`.

**Nota:** Cuando crees una pregunta agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema, toda la sección de la base de datos no influye en el problema y para no tener que crear una base de datos mejor quité esa sección.

```
import mysql.connector
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

# Crear un nuevo documento de Word
document = Document()

# Crear un nuevo estilo de párrafo personalizado
style = document.styles.add_style('CustomFont', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)

# Establecer la fuente y el tamaño de los caracteres en el estilo
style.font.name = 'Arial'
style.font.size = Pt(12)

# Agregar un título al documento
document.add_heading('Título del documento', 0)

# Obtener la primera sección del documento
section = document.add_section()
section.page_width = Inches(8.5)
section.page_height = Inches(11)
section.top_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.bottom_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.left_margin = Inches(0.75)
# Define margins
section.right_margin = Inches(0.75)

# Agregar el membrete
header = section.header
header.add_paragraph('Membrete de la empresa')

# Agregar la fecha a pie de página
footer = section.footer
parrafo = footer.add_paragraph('Fecha: ')
parrafo.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT

# Guardar el documento
document.save("prueba.docx")
```

Comment: Gracias, ya funcionó. Disculpa por lo del mysql.

Comment: No hay de que! Mientras más corto sea el código es más fácil ver el problema, por eso es importante que el ejemplo sea mínimo. Saludos!